# rails change value of parameter in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this controller

```
 def mymethod
  @theparam => (params[:valueoftheparam])
  @theparam => "3"
  callothermethodthatusetheparam
 end
```

So basically, I have "valueoftheparam" which is "2".
 I need to change the value of "2" into "3", and let "callothermethodthatusetheparam" the new param (which is "3")

however, "callothermethodthatusetheparam" in the end still used the old value("2").

How I can change this value in the controller, and let "callothermethodthatusetheparam" to use the new param value?

Thank you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to modify the value directly, the instance variable does not point to the param, it just clones its value

```
params[:valueoftheparam] = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do like this, I am sure you will get 3 printed (@params will be "3")

```
def my_method
  @param = (params[:valueoftheparam])
  @param = "3"
  other_method
end


def other_method
  puts @param
end
```

Comment: I believe what he wants is getting a 3 when he does `puts params[:valueoftheparam]` in another method

Comment: @fernando I couldnt make it out from the question...then your answer is correct...we have to set `params[:valueoftheparam] = "3"`.